# Any ways to refactor and improve a large relational databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, ssms

Are there any practices to refactor and design relational databases similar to practices in software development?

In my particular case the SQL Server database is several terabytes large, has many tables, dozens of stored procedures and a very convoluted schema. At this point there is a single instance of the database shared between the dev team (no local database instances).

Is there any way to extract a database for local testing? Can anyone share his experience of recovering from this kind of mess?

Comment: What is your actual question here? You say a mess but we have no idea what mess you are in. I would think that a terabyte sized database is not a good time to have a local copy.

Comment: Best practice would be to put a qualified and experienced DBA on it.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out a simple Google search would have solved my problem.
Here are a few resources that might help those that want to do the same thing.

- [**Refactoring Databases: Evolutionary Database Design**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774515)
- [**Recipes for Continuous Database Integration**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RH0EI4)